# How can one refer to a "class of all classes (of a certain type)"?

Tags: set-theory

Context: Self-study, working through Smullyan and Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem*, chapter 5, section $\S1$.

Please excuse the woolly language in the title.

I am proving the statement that the class of all ordinals $\mathrm{On}$ is the (unique) minimally superinductive subclass under the subset mapping.

That means:

- 1. $\mathrm{On}$ is itself superinductive under the subset mapping;
- 2. no proper subclass of $\mathrm{On}$ is itself superinductive under the subset mapping.

I am taking the definition of an ordinal as:

- $\alpha$ is an ordinal iff $\alpha$ is an element of every superinductive class.

It follows trivially that $\mathrm{On}$ is a subclass of the intersection of all superinductive classes.

(At this stage, the definition of "superinductive" is unimportant -- it's not what I am focusing on.)

It remains to be shown that $\mathrm{On}$ is itself a superinductive class.

It's a fairly straightforward plod.

But I find myself wanting to say:

> "Let $A$ be the class of all superinductive classes."

But **a class cannot contain a (proper) class**. A class can contain **nothing but sets**.

So I find myself wording part of my proof in this horribly unwieldy manner:

> "Let $M$ be an arbitrary superinductive class. Let $\alpha \in M$. Then as $M$ is superinductive, $\alpha^+ \in M$. As $M$ is arbitrary, this applies to all superinductive classes.
> Hence if $\alpha$ is in every superinductive class, then $\alpha^+$ is also in every superinductive class. Hence if $\alpha$ is in the intersection of all superinductive classes, $\alpha^+$ is also in the intersection of all superinductive classes. Hence if $\alpha \in \mathrm{On}$, then $\alpha^+ \in \mathrm{On}$."

But as I say, this is all very unwieldy.

How can this be better constructed?

Comment: I’m sure there is more to this, but I recall reading a definition where a set is a member of a universe and a class is a subset of the universe. Therefore a subset of a subset (subclass of a class) seems to be an admissible notion.

Comment: I'm not sure which framework you're working in (NBG, New Foundations, etc.), and I've only read a little about classes, but from what I've read ***sets are classes*** (of a certain kind), so if a class can contain sets, then it can contain classes. Maybe you mean that the classes it contains are not proper classes (i.e. they are sets).

Comment: @Joe Sets are classes yes, but classes are not always sets. Elements of classes cannot be proper classes, they can only be sets. Edited the question for clarity.